# Customizing Twilio SMS opt out response message

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-twiml

Is there a way to customize Twilio's SMS opt-out response message? When a user opts out, Twilio has a generic response message that I would like to customize. I know this can be done with Twilio's Messaging Service, but is there any other way this can be configured for an individual phone number? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, it has to be via Advanced Opt-out and that requires the numbers be in a messaging service.